# Recuperar informações de WebService

Tags: php, web-service, xml, soapclient

Tenho que enviar um Token de acesso para o webservice, esse token deve ser envia em um XML, como esse:

```
POST /webslaptime_deploy/websLapTime.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: 187.17.175.49
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://mylaptime.com/ListarTodosOsProdutos"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <ValidationSoapHeader xmlns="http://mylaptime.com/">
      <DevToken>string</DevToken>
    </ValidationSoapHeader>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <ListarTodosOsProdutos xmlns="http://mylaptime.com/" />
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Já tentei de várias formas, através do SOAP php, através do cURL enviando o XML digitado mesmo e nada. Sempre da este erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O DevToken está correto, verifiquei umas mil vezes.

Essas são as minhas tentativas frustradas.

Utilizando Array

```
$seg = array(
      "Header" => array(
        "ValidationSoapHeader" => array(
          "DevToken" => "DEV TOKEN AQUI"
        ),
      ),

      "Body" => array(
        "ListarTodosOsProdutos" => array()
      )
  );

  $client = new SoapClient('http://IP/webslaptime_deploy/websLapTime.asmx?WSDL');

  $function = "ListarTodosOsProdutos";
  $options = array('location' => 'http://IP/webslaptime_deploy/websLapTime.asmx');

  $result = $client->__soapCall($function, $seg, $options);
```

Utilizando OBJ

```
$seg = new StdClass;
  $seg->Header = new StdClass;
  $seg->Header->ValidationSoapHeader = new StdClass;
  $seg->Header->ValidationSoapHeader->DevToken = "DEV TOKEN AQUI";

  $seg->Body = new StdClass;
  $seg->Body->ListarTodosOsProdutos = new StdClass;

  $client = new SoapClient('http://IP/webslaptime_deploy/websLapTime.asmx?WSDL');

  $function = "ListarTodosOsProdutos";
  $options = array('location' => 'http://IP/webslaptime_deploy/websLapTime.asmx');

  $result = $client->__soapCall($function, $seg, $options);
```

Comment: O endpoint que está tentando consumir, possuí algum fator de autenticação (basic, certificado...)

Comment: Não faço ideia, o webservice não possui documentação. Foi passado apenas o XML e o devToken